# JS Flow: How to pass a param to a callback without passing it to the caller

Tags: javascript, parameters, callback, async.js

I have an object which opens an xml and change some content in it given some parameters.

I divided the object in four functions, open file, parse file, write file and the whole process caller/flow manager: generate xml, which is mainly an `async.js` waterfall.

The thing is that firs, I have to read the file and pass the contents to the parse function, but to the parse function (the second one) I need to to pass some parameters received at the generate function. How can I do this in a clean way so I don't have to pass the `config` param to the `openXML` function but pass it to the `parseXML` function?

JavaScript code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var async = require('async');

var templPathF = __dirname + '/../templates/widget_template/config.xml';
var resulPathF = __dirname + '/../results/widget_template/config.xml';


/**
 * @TODO
 *
 * [X] Find by name and attribute value
 * [X] Set content
 * [ ] Change attr
 * [X] Delete child
 * [ ] Add child
 *
 */
var pkgmgr = {

    // Open XML
    openXML: function(pathf, callback){

        fs.readFile(pathf, 'utf8', function (err, xmlString) {
            callback(null, xmlString);
        });

    },

    // Parse XML
    parseXML: function(config, xmlString, callback){

        var document = new xmldoc.XmlDocument(xmlString);
        document.descendantWithPath("name").val = 'foo';

        // Callback
        callback(null, xmlString);
    },

    // Save XML
    saveXML: function(xmlString, callback){
        console.log(xmlString);
        callback(null, xmlString);
    },

    // Generate XML
    // config: name, description
    generateXML: function(config, cb){

        var self = this;

        async.waterfall([
            // Init waterfall
            function(callback){
                callback(null, templPathF);
            },

            // Open and Read
            self.openXML,

            // Treat and change
            self.parseXML,

            // Save new file
            self.saveXML
        ]);

    }
};

module.exports = pkgmgr;
```

Answer (score 0):

use the *bind* function.

changes in the code

cheers
happy coding :)

```
var fs = require('fs');
var async = require('async');

var templPathF = __dirname + '/../templates/widget_template/config.xml';
var resulPathF = __dirname + '/../results/widget_template/config.xml';
var pkgmgr = {

    openXML: function(pathf, callback) {
        fs.readFile(pathf, 'utf8', callback);
    },

    parseXML: function(config, xmlString, callback){
        var document = new xmldoc.XmlDocument(xmlString);
        document.descendantWithPath("name").val = 'foo';

        callback(null, xmlString);
    },

    saveXML: function(xmlString, callback){
        callback(null, xmlString);
    },

    generateXML: function(config, cb){
        var self = this;
        async.waterfall([
            async.constant(templPath),
            self.openXML,
            self.parseXML.bind(self, config), // <------------ 
            self.saveXML
        ]);
    }
};
```